# How to say "patience" in latin in the modern sense of "virtue of waiting or being able to wait"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

Despite its similarity, the latin word *patientia* doesn't have the meaning of "patience" as the virtue or ability of waiting, but means more the virtue or ability of suffering r bearing something. How can I say in latin "have a little patience"? Is there any way of expressing this concept in latin?

Answer (score 7):

You may be able to express the “modern” sense by saying ***patientia morae*** (or ***morarum***). Similar constructions are [suggested by Georges](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Lateinisch_deutsches_und_deutsch_lateini/dZlEAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA1185&printsec=frontcover) for *impatientia* and *impatiens* with a nod to [Sil. Ital. 8, 4](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/silius/silius8.shtml); [Ammian. 28, 1, 9](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/ammianus/28.shtml); [Tac. Hist. 2, 40](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/tacitus/tac.hist2.shtml#40); all of which use the adjective *impatiens*. Generally what this tells me is that you might be better advised trying to find a different way to express whatever it is you want to say.

In the case of “have a little patience,” I gather this is intended to mean “wait a little while.” In that case I would translate it as ***paulisper exspecta***.